# timestamps from datetime != timestamps from pd.Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Why aren't these the same?

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

print(datetime.strptime("2021-06-01", "%Y-%m-%d").timestamp())
print(pd.Timestamp("2021-06-01").timestamp())
```

output

```
1622469600.0

1622505600.0
```

diff

```
36000.0
```

Comment: They both output the same for me. Could you post the whole code? Perhaps there's another problem.

Comment: one of the two is localizing it to your pc's timezone, while the other is in utc, and you are presumably 10 hours off from utc?  (on my pc it was a difference of 25200 which is the same as my utc offset)

Comment: pandas assumes UTC for naive date/time (= no time zone defined), native Python assumes local time (while Unix time refers to 1970-01-01 UTC).